# How to change the hyper link to checkbox link?

Tags: 7

I'm using [Node Compare](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_compare) module to compare products, it showing the **Add to Compare** as link, You can see the [DEMO here](http://nb7demo.drupalka.ru/), but I want to show as **checkbox link**

> [image].

I have no idea on how to achieve this, any pointer would be helpful!

Comment: What's a "checkbox link"? That's not an HTML element I'm familiar with. Do you mean you want the label text to contain an anchor tag?

Comment: @Clive yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can save checkbox image from [here](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/checkboxes_1.png).

```
a.compare-toggle {
    background-image: url("/path_to_image/checkboxes.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000000;
    height: 16px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.compare-toggle.add {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
a.compare-toggle.remove {
    background-position: 0 -16px;
}
```

Let me know if you face any further query/concern regarding this.